# Application of class inside interface

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

We can create a class inside an interface and we can also create interface inside a class,so  what is the use of such design pattern.

```
interface person {
    class Student {
        public String name;
    }
    Student getName();
} //i took this example from answer given below
```

can we use this design pattern in Library Management system.Do they really helpful in Development process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Create class inside an interface:**
                  If a class is small and too much tightly couple to an interface then we can declare the class inside the interface. The main purpose is used to provide a strong type to the class. A small example:

```
interface person {
    class Student {
        public String name;
    }
    Student getName();
}
```

Here Student has the strong type of person interface.

**Create interface inside a class:** It is a way to write code if the interface is small and you want to limit the visibility of the interface,

Comment: Hi this question is asked by interviewer some days before , they want the exact situation in which it is useful